# MinDate based on 1st input datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have tried many examples I have seen on this site, but just cannot seem to get this code to work.

I'm looking to stop the user from selecting a date less than the date entered in 1st textbox datepicker. But everything I try just does not seem to work.

So DepartDate must be minimum of #ArrivalDate + 1 day, I have been able to limit the number of days to 30, but minDate has got me beat.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ArrivalDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function () {
            var date2 = $('#ArrivalDate').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 30);
            $('#DepartDate').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            $('#DepartDate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date2);
        }
    });
    $('#DepartDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onClose: function () {
            //var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            //date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            calculate();
            //minDate: $('#ArrivalDate').datepicker('getDate', '+1d');
            var dteArrivalDate = $('#ArrivalDate').datepicker('getDate');
            var dteDepartDate = $('#DepartDate').datepicker('getDate');
            if (dteDepartDate <= dteArrivalDate) {
                var maxDate = $('#DepartDate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate');
                //var minDate = $('#ArrivalDate').datepicker('getDate', '+1d');
                $('#DepartDate').datepicker('setDate', maxDate);
                //$('#DepartDate').datepicker('setDate', maxDate,'minDate',date);
                //$('#DepartDate').datepicker({ setDate: maxDate, minDate: minDate });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you set maxDate, set minDate

```
var date1 = $('#ArrivalDate').datepicker('getDate');
date1.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
$('#DepartDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date1);
```

Comment: Hi dm4web, thanks I was putting the code above in the wrong place. Think i have spent looking at computer to long